# Cannot get a list of Item objects from Firestore

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a class that looks like this:

```
class Items {
    public List<Item> itemList;

    Items(List<Item> itemList) {
        this.itemList = itemList;
    }
}
```

To add the list to Firestore I use:

```
db.collection("items").add(new Items(itemList));
```

And results a documents that contains a list of `Item` objects. However, when I try to get the list back:

```
db.collection("items").document(itemId).get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
            if (document.exists()) {
                List<Item> itemList = (List<Item>) document.get("itemList");
            }
        }
    }
});
```

This is not possible. Why the vice versa doesn't work? How to get the list back as `List<Item>`?

Comment: What is exactly is the `document` variable that you're showing here?  Please edit the question to show the complete code that's not working the way you expect.

Comment: @DougStevenson That `document` is actually a `DocumentSnapshot` object. Please see my updated code.

Comment: @DougStevenson Do you need more code? Thanks

Comment: You will have to iterate the list of things you get back from `document.get("itemList")` and manually convert them into Items.

Comment: @DougStevenson Thank you Doug but what I want to say is that, that list of "things" is actually already a list of `Item` objects. Will it be helpful if I add a screenshot to see it more clearly? Thanks

Comment: Firestore doesn't retain the type of object that you add.  It's probably being stored as a Map<String, Object>, which you will have to manually convert into an Item. It will be helpful if you use a debugger and debug logging to see for yourself.

Comment: Ok, I'll do that in the way you said. But do you think that is possible one day to have this feature? Thanks

Comment: You are always free to file a feature request with Firebase support.  https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support